# django struggling with the basics reportlab

Tags: python, django

If i have a 3 tables: House > Parent > Child. How would I print data to pdf about the parent, what house they live in and what children they have.

view.py

```
def some_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

    p = canvas.Canvas(response)

    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello World.")

    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

models.py

```
class House(request):
    address = models.CharField()

class Parent(request):
    name = models.CharField()
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, related_name='parents')

class Child(request):
    name = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

Sorry for such a broad question. I just don't know were to start and struggling with the docs

Comment: Does your code work? What's the problem?

Comment: The example from above only prints out 'Hello world' how do i get the data from my models?

Comment: It is indeed too broad. Your can start addressing your problem in 3 steps - first write the query that generates the data in the required format. Second, start working how how to generate pdfs using reportlab. Then, putting these things together is the final step.

Comment: What @karthikr said. Also, if you don't know how to access data from your model, you should be reading Django's tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion how you can go about this, first some code and then some explanation:

```
HOUSE_X = ...
PARENT_X = ...
CHILD_X = ...
START_Y = ...
SEP_Y = ...

y = START_Y;
houses = House.objects.all()
for house in houses:
    p.drawString(HOUSE_X, y, house.address);
    y += SEP_Y
    parents = Parent.objects.filter(house=house)
    for parent in parents:
        p.drawString(PARENT_X, y, parent.name);
        y += SEP_Y
        children = Child.objects.filter(parent=parent)
        for child in children:
            p.drawString(CHILD_X, y, child.name);
            y += SEP_Y
```

Ok, so first of, the magic values at the top defines the x position of each model, my suggestion is that `HOUSE_X < PARENT_X < CHILD_X`to get a identation but it's up to you. Next, `START_Y` is where we start from y and `SEP_Y` is the line height that will be increased for every drawn string, you will see `y` is increased after every call to `drawString`.

Now I just looped through all the models, getting their related objects and printed those, using my magic values and increasing `y` at every step.

Hopefully this gives you a start. From here you can decide the magic values and decide exactly what should be printed on every line.